# working with UIWebViewDelegate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I've seen a number of questions about `UIWebViewDelegates` on stackoverflow, but they've been either about something different from my problem or too over my head for me to understand (or both).

My `UIWebView` loads fine, but I want to be able to take certain actions if the user clicks on a link within the webview once it's loaded.  In `viewDidLoad` I've set `self.webV.delegate = self;` (`webV` is the property that instantiates `GHWebView`, my `UIWebView` class).  In the view controller class I've added the following code, merely as a test before I start working on the actual method:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(GHWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
if (navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
{
    NSLog(@"Yes!");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"No.");
}
return YES;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get "Yes!" logged if the user clicks on a link within the loaded webview.  But when the webview loads and I click on a link in it, there's no NSLog.  What should I do differently?

(Thanks in advance for your help and for your patience with somebody who doesn't yet understand delegates....)

**EDIT:** Okay, here's what I think is the relevant code in GHWebView.  *As of now,* in `GHWebView.h` I declare the properties requ (`NSURLRequest`), conn (`NSURLConnection`), and urlData (`NSData`) as well as a method, `-(void)loadWebViewWithbaseURLString:bus withURLString:us`.  Then in `GHWebView.m` I define the method:

```
-(void)loadWebViewWithbaseURLString:bus withURLString:us
{
self.requ = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:us] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval: 20];
self.conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:self.requ delegate:nil];
NSError *error=nil;
NSURLResponse *resp=nil;
if (self.conn)
{
    self.urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: self.requ returningResponse:&resp error:&error];
    NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:bus]];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
    alert.title = @"Unfortunately, I seem to be having a hard time connecting to the Internet.  Would you mind trying again later?  I'll make it worth your while, I promise.";
    [alert show];
}
}
```

I know that I have to declare a delegate and also add a protocol to my header file -- I think it would involve adding code like

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<UIWebViewDelegate> delegate;

@protocol GHWebViewDelegate <UIWebView>
-(void)loadWebViewWithbaseURLString:bus withURLString:us;
@end
```

But then when I got back to the implementation file and try to replace the `self`s with `self.delegate`s in the method `-(void)loadWebViewWithbaseURLString:bus withURLString:us`, I get `property not found on object of type` errors.  What ought I to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention you are setting the delegate to the ViewController that is responsible for instantiating the `GHWebView` class. Whilst that is fine, my question is do you have a section in your `GHWebView` class where you assign this object as the delegate of the `UIWebView` so that it can respond to the `-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType` method and then call the `webView:(GHWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` so that when this protocol method gets called your delegate (in your case your ViewController) can attend the call?

Comment: No, I don't!  So far in my very limited experience I've only assigned delegates in parent classes, not child classes, so I'm a little bit at sea--I know a little, but that, as we and Alexander Pope know, is a dangerous thing.  I'm going to edit my question to show you what I DO know, or what I think I know, in the hope that you'll correct my errors and fill in the gaps in my understanding.  Thank you so very much for your help.

Comment: One thing that I notice from the code you added to your question is: Your property called delegate is of type `UIWebView` what you want there is to be of type `GHWebView` as it will be the delegate responsible of the protocols of this class. You will probably want to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c

Comment: Thanks very much--both for noticing what you noticed and for pointing me to that helpful question/answer!